# How do I change the font-family of a <button> element?

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is my only CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'thefont';
  src: url('fonts/the-font.otf');
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'thefont';
}
```

When I do a `<button>Hi</button>` the font ends up being `-apple-system`.

If I actually assign the font to `button`, it will make the font appear.

Does anyone know why it's not affecting the body and everything inside it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In addition to the info below, to ensure your custom font is being taken into account for the button, you need to apply

```
button {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

to all button elements.

You can inspect how they do it there:

https://purecss.io/buttons/

or there:

https://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Also make sure that your font is exported in several different formats so that it is supported by all platforms.

You can use [FontSquirrel Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to export your font to all formats.

Your CSS should look a bit like that:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'thefont';
  src: url('the-font.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('the-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('the-font.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('the-font.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('the-font.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('the-font.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Thanks george, what a silly mistake. I will mark this answer when it let's me.

Comment: For some reason, it's still not working inside the button, is there any tests I can do to make sure that's the issue? It's working on `<a>` but not in `<button>`. If I do `body * { font-family: 'font'; }` it works but it seems hacky

Comment: so, button { font-family: 'thefont', sans-serif; } doesn't work? Can you check the computer CSS properties on Dev Tools and see what is applied/and why?

Comment: It's applying the user agent style for some reason. Even if I change it to a regular web font it won't change.