# How to change the font style/size of text within a button

Tags: html, css, button

I am using bootstrap and CSS to style my website but I can't seem to figure out how to change the font style and weight of the text within my buttons. Here is some of my code

```
<button type="button-apple" class="btn btn-light btn-lg download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
```

I would like to change the font to be bolder so the words are easier to read because on my screen they come out as very thin lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well i've tried things like making a unique class for the button and then trying to chane  the font family in CSS or the font weight even the background colour just to see if it was having any effect but nothing changes. Not sure what other ways there are to change it.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163454/how-do-i-change-the-font-family-of-a-button-element helps?

Comment: So this is what I tried in CSS: 
.button-apple {
  font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it**. Also, the markup does not use that class `button-apple`

Comment: Sorry Nico, idk how to edit my question, it only comes up with the delete option. Also I just realised when you mentioned mark up what my mistake was and now I've fixed it haha!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you try to work into libraries, please keep in mind that, **you are overriding the style they already defined**. In that case, just defining new styles such as color, font-weight etc. will not work. And also, **please don't try to modify the class names they are already using**.

**You Can solve it in several ways**

> **First Method** is to add a new class from your own example: here -> `.my-button-class` and try to do
> the styling. Then use `!important` with that, it will override the
> style you want.

For Example

Your HTML will be as follow:

```
<button type="button-apple" class="btn btn-light btn-lg download-button my-button-class">
<i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download
</button>
```

**CSS** for the first method

```
.my-button-class{
    font-weight: bolder !important;
    font-size: 2rem !important;
    color: blue !important;
};
```

> **Second Method** using `specificity` which is calling a class inside of a tag for example: `button.my-button-class` to style it instead of using `!important`, that's also a very good solution.

**CSS** for the second method

```
button.my-button-class{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: blue;
};
```

Hope it will solve your problem. :)

Thanks

Comment: Good advise on working with UI libraries, but `!important` declarations wouldn't be necessary here. Instead you could just add more specificity, e.g. `button.my-button-class`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just shared what I did for my last project. Will try your technique next time :)

Comment: I already did it and gave you credit with the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but don't need the credit. Just thinking of what makes a quality answer for the rest of the community. I would add why it is a better solution to further improve your answer, so that beginners starting out understand why and can avoid falling into some bad patterns early on. Understanding specificity in css in key.

Comment: I updated the answer, I believe you will like it more :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your button text in an anchor and then use a `span` item:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg download-button">
    <i class="fab fa-google-play"></i>
    <span style="font-weight:bolder;">Download</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend inline styling for 2 reasons: 1. you have to edit the DOM for a style change, 2. too specific, the specificity here cannot be overwritten or overqualified by external style rules unless you reach for `!important` declarations, which is not the right use-case for those declarations and opens up a whole other can of specificity worms.
This is a specificity issue, a cascade issue, or the custom stylesheet that isn't being loaded in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip man, started an online course recently and learning from scatch so I'll be sure to apply this advice in future.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, yes I agree, but I wanted to share a specific solution to the problem. If this button is only in one view, I think the inline styling is justified.